# What is the quickest way to determine if two elements are in the same row or column in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, data-structures

As part of one of my programs, I'm trying to check if two elements in a 2D array are part of the same row or column. I know there might be many ways to go about this, mainly with loops and by iterating through the array, but I was just wondering: is there any quick way to determine this?

Let's say I have a 2D array that looks like `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}`. Would there be any fast way to determine that `1` and `2` belong to the same row? Almost in a way that it could be evaluated in an if statement as *"if item `x` belongs to the same row as item `y`, then do so and so"*? If not, then what would be the quickest way otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach for rows.

```java
int[][] v = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
System.out.println(rowContains(v, 2, 3));
System.out.println(rowContains(v, 5, 6));
```

Prints

```
false
true
```

The method

- stream single d array and ignore duplicates
- count filter on finding the values.
- return true if any final count is 2.

```java
public static boolean rowContains(int[][] v, int v1, int v2) {
    return Arrays.stream(v)
            .map(arrs -> Arrays.stream(arrs)
                    .distinct().filter(a -> a == v1 || a == v2)
                    .count()).anyMatch(a -> a == 2);
}
```

For columns, the easiest way would be to write a method to transpose the columns and rows and re-run the method.

Answer (score 1):

This task is easier to solve with *rows* than with *columns*. You can use [`binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,%20int)) method.

This solution also works with ragged 2d arrays and an unlimited number of elements to search for.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}};
    System.out.println(sameRow(arr, 4, 5)); // true
    System.out.println(sameCol(arr, 3, 8)); // true
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param arr      2d array.
 * @param elements 1d array of elements to search for.
 * @return whether any column of a 2d array contains all elements from a 1d array.
 */
public static boolean sameCol(int[][] arr, int... elements) {
    return IntStream
            // iterate through the columns
            .iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
            // take an array of values from the column, if any
            .mapToObj(i -> Arrays
                    // iterate through the rows
                    .stream(arr)
                    // take those rows where this column is present
                    .filter(row -> row.length > i)
                    // take the value from the column
                    .mapToInt(row -> row[i])
                    // int[] - column
                    .toArray())
            // until the columns are still present
            .takeWhile(col -> col.length > 0)
            // whether any column contains all the search elements
            .anyMatch(col -> containsAll(col, elements));
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param arr      2d array.
 * @param elements 1d array of elements to search for.
 * @return whether any row of a 2d array contains all elements from a 1d array.
 */
public static boolean sameRow(int[][] arr, int... elements) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(row -> containsAll(row, elements));
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param a first array.
 * @param b second array.
 * @return whether the first array contains all elements from the second array.
 */
public static boolean containsAll(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return Arrays.stream(b).allMatch(i -> Arrays.binarySearch(a, i) > -1);
}
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [Filling a jagged 2d array first by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67066328/15613375)

• [Check if one array is a subset of the other array - special case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67131110/15613375)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This code works in *Java 7* without *streams*. The approach is the same using [`binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,%20int)) method. Ragged 2d arrays and an unlimited number of elements to search for are accepted.

And also with *loops*, this task is easier to solve with *rows* than with *columns*.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}};
    System.out.println(sameRow(arr, 4, 5));    // true
    System.out.println(sameCol(arr, 3, 8));    // true
    System.out.println(sameCol(arr, 2, 5, 7)); // true
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param arr      2d array.
 * @param elements 1d array of elements to search for.
 * @return whether any column of a 2d array contains all elements from a 1d array.
 */
public static boolean sameCol(int[][] arr, int... elements) {
    // iterate through the columns
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        // take an array of values from the column, if any
        int[] col = new int[arr.length];
        // column counter
        int j = 0;
        // iterate through the rows
        for (int[] row : arr)
            // take those rows where this column is present
            if (row.length > i)
                // take the value from the column
                // and increase the counter
                col[j++] = row[i];
        // until the columns are still present
        if (j == 0) break;
        // if this column contains all the search elements
        if (containsAll(Arrays.copyOf(col, j), elements))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param arr      2d array.
 * @param elements 1d array of elements to search for.
 * @return whether any row of a 2d array contains all elements from a 1d array.
 */
public static boolean sameRow(int[][] arr, int... elements) {
    for (int[] row : arr)
        if (containsAll(row, elements))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param a first array.
 * @param b second array.
 * @return whether the first array contains all elements from the second array.
 */
public static boolean containsAll(int[] a, int[] b) {
    for (int i : b)
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(a, i) < 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```